# Websphere portal session timeout redirect

Tags: websphere-portal

In my websphere portal 8 I need to redirect user to custom page after session timeout.
As was described in all tutorials I set

redirect.logout     = true

redirect.logout.url = /wps/portal/uec/uechidden/sessiontimeout

in WP_ConfigService but  that had no effect.
I have check all access permissions to redirect page and portlet and other.
Also I have Logout filter in my app, but even when I removed it I've been redirected to "Your portal session has timed out because of no activity. Please start a new session at your portal Home."
My timeout settings are set for server not for one application.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To redirect to the login page (or any other page) when the session expires, use one of the following methods:

Option 1. 
Extend the authentication filter chain and implement the desired logic in code. Refer to the following articles for more information: "Configuring authentication filters" and " New security APIs in WebSphere Portal".

Option 2: 
Modify the ErrorSessionTimeOut jsp to add Java script to redirect to the login page when the session times out. This option is simpler to implement but you may see a momentary "flash" when the redirect occurs.

More information: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21419230

Comment: sorry, of course I have redirect.logout and redirect.logout.url, not redirect.login...

Comment: I have rewritten the answer. It appears that after version 6.1.0.1 (and the document does apply to version 8.0) the redirect.logout parameters do not work as you want them to work. All is described in the referenced link and the solution is taken from the same place.

Answer (score 0):

To redirect the user to custom page after session times out, you need to perform following steps.

1. Define ImplicitLogoutFilter by implementing com.ibm.portal.auth.ImplicitLogoutFilter.
2. While defining ImplicitLogoutFilter, set the the redirect url in filterChainContext using method:

   filterChainContext.setRedirectURL("URL of custom page where user should be redirected to");
3. Configure this filter in web sphere.
4. In WP_ConfigService, create a new custom property redirect.logout=true
5. Restart the server.

Follow these steps, it works when session times out and user try to view authenticated page. In case any issue is faced, please let me know. I'll help you in resolving this issue..